# Issue with sorting and output

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I got one problem with sorting and output. I have no idea how should I do that.

The main idea of the program:

1. Input total amount of passengers.
2. Input total amount of cells.
3. Input passengers's data n-times (based on the first input) - ex.: Qwe 11:25 12:34.
4. Output sorted data. Output should be like this: name of the passenger, cell number.

```
n = int(input())
k = int(input())
data = []

for x in range(1,n+1):
    data.append(input().replace(":"," ").split(" "))


for elem in data:
    elem.append(int(elem[1])*60+int(elem[2]))
    elem.append(int(elem[3])*60+int(elem[4]))

    while len(elem)>3:
        elem.pop(1)

    if elem[1]>elem[2]:
        raise SystemExit("time of issuing can not be lower than time putting")
```

Example input of the program:

```
4    
2     
Qwe 12:45 16:30    
Wer 13:55 17:50    
Ert 6:25 12:55    
Rew 22:55 23:30
```

Output:

```
Ert 1    
Qwe 2
Wer 2    
Rew 1
```

"Wer" also can be skipped, because of cells limit (it's a beginning exercise, so it doesn't really mean you need such a good code that will cover everything). I can try to explain how cells work, but I think it's pretty clear from the example output - it's based on time of issuing and time putting comparation.

I'm trying to learn Python, and will be grateful if anyone will answer what should I probably do to complete my script, or rather use another idea for it.

**Upd:**
I got something like this:

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda elem: elem[1])
for elem in data: #Just visual check
    print(elem)

for x in data:
    if j<=k:
        if data[i][2]>data[i+1][1]:
            print(data[i][0], j+1)
            j+=1
            i+=1
        else:
            j=0
            print(data[i][0], j+1)
    else:
        j=0
```

But it's still not quite what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can learn the basics of Python in about five minutes from the [Sorting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/sorting.html).

In your script, it appears you are properly parsing the times but are losing the passenger info at `elem[0]`.  You will need that for the final sort.   Also, you've appended all the data into one list instead of keeping the row separate (which is necessary for sorting).

Spending a few minutes with the Sorting HowTo will help you see how to organize your data to make it sortable.

Comment: Got something like 

data = sorted(data, key=lambda elem: elem[1])

but any idea how can I track the cell number properly? I mean, need to compare elem[2] with next elem[1] and repeat it? I'm pretty unsure what should I do.